# Issue with merging AR queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been trying all different ways of combining to queries but I'm not having any luck at all. It's either returning one or the other depending on what query I put first. I want it so that it takes all the entries of `for_group_with_account` and all the entries of `for_task_with_account` and make one list. It's not the conditions that I want combined but the results of each of them combined. Hope that makes sense.

Here's the scopes in my tickets model:

```
  scope :for_group_with_account, lambda { |account| joins(:group => :accounts).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
  scope :for_task_with_account, lambda { |account| joins(:tasks => :account).where("accounts.id = ?", account.id) }
  scope :for_account, lambda { |account| for_task_with_account(account).merge(for_group_with_account(account)) }
```

For the last scope where I combine the scopes I've also tried:

```
  scope :for_account, lambda { |account| for_task_with_account(account) + for_group_with_account(account) }
  scope :for_account, lambda { |account| for_task_with_account(account) & for_group_with_account(account) }
  scope :for_account, lambda { |account| for_task_with_account(account) && for_group_with_account(account) }
```

Still none of these are actually taking the two listings and combining them. Very very frustrating. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :for_account, lambda { |account| for_task_with_account(account).for_group_with_account(account) }
```

Comment: Nope. That ends up giving me the results only `for_group_with_account(account)` which is what some of those other scopes are doing.

Comment: scopes only can be chained, maybe you want simple class method?